# Get an attribute from a struct in a Vec of structs

Tags: rust

I am trying to filter a vector of structs by a struct attribute and then return another attribute. However I'm not quite sure how to elegantly extract the value.

My function will take in the name of a budget and then I want to return the id of that budget by searching through a list of `Budget`s.

Is there a cleaner way to do this in one pass without allocating a new struct?

```
// Budget structs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Budgets {
    pub budgets: Vec<Budget>
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Budget {
    pub id: String,
    name: String,
    last_modified_on: String,
    first_month: String,
    last_month: String,
    date_format: DateFormat,
    currency_format: Option<CurrencyFormat>,
    accounts: Option<Accounts>,
}

impl Adapter {
    fn get_budget_id(&self, budget_name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        let budget_data = self.get_budgets()?;
        let budget = budget_data.data.budgets.into_iter()
            .filter(|b| b.name == budget_name);
        //.collect::<Budgets>()  <-- FromIterator not implemented
        //.remove(0);
        let b = Budgets {
            budgets: Vec::from_iter(budget)
        };
        if b.budgets.is_empty() {
            Err(anyhow::anyhow!("Error, no budget with {} name found", budget_name))
        } else {
            Ok(b.budgets[0].id.clone())
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `budget.next()` to just get the item?

Comment: @MB-F Thanks for the suggestion. This actually led me to the `find` method that seems to work, as posted below.

Answer (score 2):

After some deeper digging into the docs and suggestions on here, this was my final solution:

```
fn get_budget_id(&self, budget_name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        let budget_data = self.get_budgets()?;
        if let Some(budget) = budget_data.data.budgets.into_iter()
            .find(|b| b.name == budget_name) {
            Ok(budget.id)
        } else {
            Err(anyhow::anyhow!("Error, no budget with name {} found", budget_name))
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Steve Martinez you can use the `ok_or` as outlined in my response to avoid the if let else

Comment: Just be careful with `into_iter()` because that _consumes_ the original collection.  Just `.iter()` is what you want if you just want to look through it and borrow without destroying the original.  For toy examples it doesn't matter, but if `self.get_budgets()` returns a copy (and not a reference), this will get expensive with larger "real-world" examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
let budget:Budget = budget_data.data.budgets.into_iter()
    .find(|b| b.name == budget_name)
    .ok_or(anyhow::anyhow!("Error, no budget with {} name found", budget_name))?;
```